# postgresql v8.4 function runs but doesn't work

Tags: functions, postgresql-8.4

I have a postgresql v8.4 database. I need to update several hundred tables with about 3 million rows of data each.

The customer wants a new column added (which I added) and now I'm trying to update the new column with data.

I created some SQL statements to do the update. This works if I run it manually in pgAdmin (just the sql statements); so I tried putting this into a function to automate the UPDATE, like so:

```
CREATE or REPLACE function update_ee() RETURN void as
$$
DECLARE
  row RECORD; 
BEGIN
   FOR row IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' and tablename like '%_2015060%' order by tablename asc;
   LOOP
   RAISE LOG 'removing index for %', row.tablename;
   -- remove indices
   EXECUTE 'DROP INDEX ' || row.tablename || '_start_idx;';

   RAISE LOG 'starting update on %', row.tablename; 
   -- update table
   EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || row.tablename || ' set ee = array_to_string(regexp_matches(xml_data, ''<EE_ID>(.+?)</EE_ID>''), '';'') where elnot is NULL and xml_data is not null;'; 

   RAISE LOG 'restoring index on %', row.tablename; 
   -- put indices back
   EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || row.tablename || '_start_idx on ' || row.tablename || ' USING btree(start);'; 
   END LOOP;
  RETURN;
 END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So the function runs; the updates tend to slow down a bit with each successive table; the log statements all appear in the log file. It appears to be working; but upon finish not one table has been updated.

What did I do wrong?

Is it not possible to update tables from a function? Is the language wrong? Should I use SQL instead of plsql?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying the original function code under Postgres 9.3, it would not compile.  I had to change 2 minor things, which I have commented and labelled *1* and *2*.  Testing the function with several small tables worked like a charm - I have used Postgres 9.3 and 8.4 (see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=c8c76d881856618e0774c91095392483)).
Example code:

```
create table a_2017 (id int primary key, start int);
create index a_2017_start_idx on a_2017 using btree(start) ;
create table b_2017 (id int primary key, start int);
create index b_2017_start_idx on b_2017 using btree(start) ;
create table c_2017 (id int primary key, start int);
create index c_2017_start_idx on c_2017 using btree(start) ;
create table d_2017 (id int primary key, start int);
create index d_2017_start_idx on d_2017 using btree(start) ;
create table e_2017 (id int primary key, start int);
create index e_2017_start_idx on e_2017 using btree(start) ;


insert into a_2017 values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5);
insert into b_2017 values (11,11),(22,22),(33,33),(44,44),(55,55);
insert into c_2017 values (111,111),(222,222),(333,333),(444,444),(555,555);
insert into d_2017 values (1111,1111),(2222,2222),(3333,3333),(4444,4444),(5555,5555);
insert into e_2017 values (11111,11111),(22222,22222),(33333,33333),(44444,44444),(55555,55555);
```

Function: *1* returns (instead of: return), *2* no semicolon.  select in round brackets.

```
create or replace function update_2017() 
returns void -- <--_1_
as $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD; 
BEGIN
   FOR row IN ( 
     SELECT tablename 
     FROM pg_tables 
     WHERE schemaname = 'public' and tablename like '%_2017%' 
     order by tablename asc ) -- <--_2_
   LOOP
      RAISE LOG '-> removing index for %', row.tablename;
      -- remove indices
      EXECUTE 'DROP INDEX ' || row.tablename || '_start_idx;';

      RAISE LOG '--> starting update on %', row.tablename; 
      -- update table
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || row.tablename || ' set start = start*1000;'; 

      RAISE LOG '---> restoring index on %', row.tablename; 
      -- put indices back
      EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || row.tablename || '_start_idx on ' || row.tablename || ' USING btree(start);'; 
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, for testing the function:

```
select update_2017();

select * from a_2017
union
select * from b_2017
union
select * from c_2017
union
select * from d_2017
union
select * from e_2017
;
```

-- output: see last section of the [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=c8c76d881856618e0774c91095392483).

With bigger tables (one million rows), the execution of the function was slightly slower, but worked nonetheless.  Maybe you should have another shot at this ...